# Spark Type mismatch: cannot convert from DataFrame to Dataset<Row>

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-dataset

I am getting a weird error saying

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from DataFrame to Dataset<Row>
```

When I am trying to implement the example code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158954/how-to-create-a-simple-spark-graphframe-using-java]).

This is the line which gives me the error.

```
    Dataset<Row> verDF = spark.createDataFrame(uList, User.class);
```

I also took a look at the documentation of Spark [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection), which gives the same example. But I am not sure why it is not working in my case.

Here are my `imports`:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.graphx.*;
import org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.*;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel;
import org.graphframes.GraphFrame;

import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.collection.Iterator;
import scala.collection.immutable.Map;
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq;
```

Here are the related dependencies:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>SparkPackagesRepo</id>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>graphframes</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphframes</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-graphx_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. I used the following dependencies and used the `SparkSession` instance to create the dataframe.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```